# Comparação de pontos geográficos no postgres

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, geolocalização, postgis

**Tenho uma estrutura mais ou menos assim:**

Uma tabela `veiculo` onde armazeno o `id` e a `placa` do veiculo.

Uma tabela `estacionamento` onde armazeno o `nome do estacionamento`, o `id` e a `area` dele (um polígono utilizando o [**postgis**](http://www.postgis.net/).

Uma tabela `ponto de interesse` onde capturo a `localização atual` do meu veículo. (esses dados vão ser inseridos na mão através de um *Webservice*.

Quando eu envio um `ponto de interesse` para o banco, preciso criar uma função que verifique se o ponto está dentro de um estacionamento, e caso retorne `true`, é necessário que se abra uma comanda e grave a data de entrada.

**Minha dificuldade consiste no seguinte:**

Vou capturando pontos do automóvel, e preciso comparar o ponto atual com o ponto anterior, para saber se ele ainda está dentro do estacionamento ou já saiu, exemplo.

- Se ele estava fora e continua fora, não faz nada.
- Se ele estava fora e entrou, abre uma comanda.
- Se ele estava dentro e continua dentro não faz nada.
- Se ele estava dentro e agora está fora, fecha a comanda.

Para verificar se está dentro, estou usando o `St_within` do [**postgis**](http://www.postgis.net/), mas para não consegui pensar em como fazer a comparação do ponto anterior com o atual de forma eficaz.

Alguém pode me informar algum norte para que eu possa seguir?